# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для сайта GD Browser

Tags: javascript

[image]

Мне надо составить регулярное выражение для нахождения чисел в этой строке, вот ссылка на страницу https://gdbrowser.com/u/Smiffy777

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы реализовываете на JS, вы можете попробовать использовать `DOMParser`, с его помощью можно получить следующий код:

```js
async function getUserData(user)
{
  const text = await fetch("https://gdbrowser.com/u/" + user).then((res) => res.text());
  const html = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, "text/html");

  const data = 
  {
    stars: parseInt(html.querySelector("#stars").textContent),
    diamonds: parseInt(html.querySelector("#diamonds").textContent),
    coins: parseInt(html.querySelector("#coins").textContent),
    usercoins: parseInt(html.querySelector("#usercoins").textContent),
    demons: parseInt(html.querySelector("#demons").textContent)
  }

  return data;
}

getUserData("Smiffy777").then((data) => console.info(data));
```

В нем мы отправим отправим запрос на наш сайт и получим всю `html` разметку, дальше мы ее распарсим с помощью DOMParser и сможем обращаться к элементам с помощью `js` методов.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я вас правильно понял, регулярное выражение здесь очень простое:

```
\d+
```

`\d` означает десятичную цифру, и `+` значит, что таких цифр может быть одна или более.

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё исключение текста перед и после числе, т.к. при такой регулярке оно вернёт `777`, что является ником пользователя **Smiffy777**

Comment: @De.Minov, *"... в этой строке..."* (из текста и картинки в вопрoсе).

Comment: Ну.. Мне почему-то вообще, кажется, что автор будет проходить по всему документу)